# Why am I not able to capture the stdout of python subprocesses in QProcess using its signal `readyRead`?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, stdout, openai-whisper

A bit of a complicated question:

When I run this:

```cpp
QProcess p_Whisper;
p_Whisper.setArguments( QStringList()
<< "--model"                      << "medium.en"
<< "--output_dir"                 << d_Hidden.absolutePath()
<< "--task"                       << "transcribe"
<< "--language"                   << "en"
<< "--condition_on_previous_text" << "False"
<< "--no_speech_threshold"        << "0.5"
<< "--logprob_threshold"          << "None"
<< "--threads"                    << "8"
<< "--fp16"                       << "False"
<< "--verbose"                    << "True"
<< f.fileName()
);
p_Whisper.setProgram("/home/anon/.local/bin/whisper");
```

The output from a shell would be like this:

```bash
/home/anon/.local/bin/whisper --model tiny.en --output_dir /home/anon/Music/AF/.transcripts --task transcribe --language en --condition_on_previous_text False --no_speech_threshold 0.5 --logprob_threshold None --threads 8 "/home/anon/Music/AF/CORONAVIRUS PANDEMIC - New Cases in France, Chicago- Virus Spreading RAPIDLY _ America First Ep. 53..-OoFCDcxBbvQ.m4a"  
/home/anon/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/whisper/transcribe.py:78: UserWarning: FP16 is not supported on CPU; using FP32 instead
  warnings.warn("FP16 is not supported on CPU; using FP32 instead")
[00:00.000 --> 00:02.000]  For the king of the nation,
[00:02.000 --> 00:04.000]  for the king of the nation.
[00:04.000 --> 00:06.000]  Go be on the wheel!
[00:34.000 --> 00:40.120]  Not interested. I'm sorry. I'm sorry for the eventy, but I just can't do it. You're an e-girl. You know the world
[00:40.240 --> 00:48.080]  No e-girls who's got to clip don't eat girls never hashtag never e-girls not even once
[00:48.080 --> 00:55.080]  Yeah, I don't have to ever heard of it, but what is this that?
[01:48.080 --> 02:03.080]  Yeah, I've never heard of bigfoots, who's that?
```

In Qt, I try to capture the output using this:

```cpp
connect( &p_Whisper, &QProcess::readyReadStandardError,[this, &p_Whisper](){
    ct_Error( p_Whisper.readAllStandardError() );
});
connect( &p_Whisper, &QProcess::readyReadStandardOutput,[this, &p_Whisper](){
    QString s = p_Whisper.readAllStandardOutput();
    ct_Process(s);
    ui->textBrowser->append(s);
});
```

But the following output is never captured:

```bash
[00:00.000 --> 00:02.000]  For the king of the nation,
[00:02.000 --> 00:04.000]  for the king of the nation.
[00:04.000 --> 00:06.000]  Go be on the wheel!
[00:34.000 --> 00:40.120]  Not interested. I'm sorry. I'm sorry for the eventy, but I just can't do it. You're an e-girl. You know the world
[00:40.240 --> 00:48.080]  No e-girls who's got to clip don't eat girls never hashtag never e-girls not even once
[00:48.080 --> 00:55.080]  Yeah, I don't have to ever heard of it, but what is this that?
[01:48.080 --> 02:03.080]  Yeah, I've never heard of bigfoots, who's that?
```

I think it might be due to the fact that subprocesses seem to be generating that output. Thus, I tried using this line:

```cpp
connect( &p_Whisper, &QProcess::channelReadyRead,[this, &p_Whisper](int channel){
    p_Whisper.setCurrentReadChannel(channel);
    QString s = p_Whisper.readAllStandardOutput();
    ct_Process(s);
    ui->textBrowser->append(s);
});
```

But that did not fire.
I also tried this:

```
p_Whisper.setProcessChannelMode( QProcess::ForwardedChannels );
```

And that did not cause the signals to fire [which would allow me to capture the stdout], but it did forward it to my shell running the program:

[image: Explanation: The stdout is overwriting my custom TUI environment. Ordinarily I capture the stdout first, and format it into something TUI readable.]

### Additional Details:

From what I gather, whisper are a bunch of c subprocesses wrapped in python. I think that might be relevant if the subprocesses output are handled differently.

### Questions:

1. What exactly is the reason why the stdout is not being captured by `QProcess`'s `readyRead` signals?
2. Are subprocesses outputted on different channels, referenced in `QProcess`?
3. Can I use `QProcess` to actually capture the relevant `stdout`? I am thinking there is perhaps an environment variable that could help here.

Thanks.

Edit:

---

Some additional testing, when I ran this in the shell:

```bash
/home/anon/.local/bin/whisper --model tiny.en --output_dir /home/anon/Music/AF/.transcripts --task transcribe --language en --condition_on_previous_text False --no_speech_threshold 0.5 --logprob_threshold None --threads 8 "/home/anon/Music/AF/CORONAVIRUS PANDEMIC - New Cases in France, Chicago- Virus Spreading RAPIDLY _ America First Ep. 53..-OoFCDcxBbvQ.m4a" 1> /tmp/stdout.txt 2>/tmp/stderr.txt
```

Wherein it outputs stdout and stderr to seperate files, the stdout did in fact pickup the expected output successfully, although it took quite a long time to do so. There was some speculation that whisper was changing its behaviour if it was being ran in a terminal, but it appears not to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the output is massively delayed.

After about 8 hours of running it, did the output finally make its way through this lambda:

```
connect( &p_Whisper, &QProcess::channelReadyRead,[this, &p_Whisper](int channel){
    p_Whisper.setCurrentReadChannel(channel);
    QString s = p_Whisper.readAllStandardOutput();
    ct_Process(s);
    ui->textBrowser->append(s);
});
```

As to why it took much longer than when running from a shell, I have no idea.